# Facing Issue while installing MySQL with Linux

Tags: linux, mysql

I am facing a weird issue while installing MySQL on Linux machine.

I was trying to configure MySQL as backend database to work on Airflow.
Below are my configurations:

```
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7
python 3.7.2
anaconda 3
spark 2.45
```

I am able to connect to MySQL but facing an error while running airflow initdb command. Not sure why this error is happening but certainly it's due to MySQL only.

**Error:**

```
[2020-04-09 05:19:00,990] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=15499
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 377, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 266, in configure_orm
    engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, **engine_args)
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
  File "/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: /home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol mysql_real_escape_string_quote, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference
```

Comment: You probably need to do something like `conda install mysqlclient`

Comment: @ Gerrit. still same error

Comment: how did you install mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything but finally I have to remove everything from server and installed anaconda and MySQL again to fix the issue.

I get finally below commands from SO which worked. for some reasons MySQL was corrupted and was not uninstalling properly. Here are few which finally worked and removed MySQL completely from my system.

```
yum remove mysql-server
pkill mysqld; pkill mysqld_safe
rpm -qa | grep mysql
yum remove <name displayed in above step-1>
sudo -H pip uninstall mysqlclient
sudo -H pip install --no-binary mysqlclient mysqlclient

rm -rf ~/anaconda3
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean
```

Thereafter I install and configured anaconda and MySQL again and issue was resolved.

Comment: Uninstalling mysql was unnecessary, I think. The root of the problem probably was that pip was using an anaconda2 environment and compiled the wrong rpath into the mysql python wrapper library.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a symbolic link to the library. I.e.

The actual library resides in

```
/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

And then I created a symbolic link in

```
/usr/lib
```

Using the command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_18 /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_18
```

so that I have the following mapping:

```
ls -l libmysqlclient_18 

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  44 16 Jul 14:01 libmysqlclient_18 -> /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_18
```

Comment: ok.. I don't see any mysql folder at given location /usr/local

Comment: I can see mysql folder at below location only. [npa@innolx5984 ~]$ find /home/npa/ -name "mysql"
/home/npa/anaconda3/pkgs/sqlalchemy-1.3.13-py37h7b6447c_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql
/home/npa/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql
/home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql

Comment: Can you find it using: `sudo find / -name "mysql"`

Comment: /usr/bin/mysql
/usr/lib64/mysql
/usr/share/mysql

Comment: Are you able to find any drivers related to `libmysqlclient` use commands to find :`ls -ltr /usr/bin/mysql/lib/* | grep libmysqlclient` for all locations.

Comment: mysql is not a directory in bin

Comment: Doesn't the `/usr/lib64/mysql` directory have the libmysqlclient.18.so?

Comment: @ Gerrit- Yes it has.. below are the files available.

libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
libmysqlclient_r.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
libmysqlclient.so.21.1.19
libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
libmysqlclient.so.21 -> libmysqlclient.so.21.1.19

Comment: @Gerrit.what would be the next step to fix this? Kindly suggest

Comment: `python-dev libmysqlclient-dev` Do you have these dependencies installed at OS level & you probably needs to copy mysql clients driver to your path where you code is looking for it `cp /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 <your package path>`

Comment: @vikrantrana, apparently the compilation of anaconda python mysql only looks in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib and not in a mysql subdirectory. A copy of the mysqlclient lib to one of those should help. You could also use `readelf -d /home/npa/anaconda3/envs/python3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and look for the `rpath` constant to see where it would look. `readelf` should be in packages `binutils` if it is not installed.

Comment: @Gerrit-- Yeah path is Library rpath: [/home/npa/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/lib] and it doesn't have file "*libmysqlclient*"

Comment: something is going wrong with rpath it is looking in anaconda2 version which was installed earlier. I have switched to anaconda3

Comment: Working now? :-)

Comment: @Gerrit. Not yet  not sure why RPATH is still pointing to previous version of anaconda even when that path doesn't exist. I am totally clueless now. Not sure how can I fix this

Comment: The quick fix would be to: `mkdir -p /home/npa/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/lib` and `ln -s /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.so /home/npa/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/lib/libmysqlclient.18.so`. But this can break any time you update something in anaconda. Maybe you should try anaconda3 under a new user.

Comment: Maybe you have a LD_LIBRARY_PATH left from previous anaconda2? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only

Comment: Well, all I can tell you is that you've installed mysql incorrectly.  Use package manager and packages.